# How to fix Cross Site Scripting Weakness (Persistent in JSON Response and Reflected in Json Response )

Tags: json, security, asp.net-core, owasp

Hi so I scan my Website using ZAP https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project , and get some vulnerability message, I already fix a couple of vulnerability  but I still didn't get about this How to fix Cross-Site Scripting Weakness (Persistent in JSON Response and Reflected in Json Response ) message, When I look on the internet they say I need to use application/JSON  to all my JSON Response, But I thought asp net core already handle that when I return Ok(_repository.GetDataExample());. What should I do to fix that vulnerability?

Comment: could  you try  implementing more setting with CORS

Comment: @kunalverma can you give me any source I can look into? thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: HI @kunalverma , can you be more specific, what exactly are Cors setting should I add here?

Comment: CORS setting can be added in web.config ...or programantically  .....in which technology is your site made

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsnuIZX1C9A